# Build trigger failed in Container Registry

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I created a trigger in Container Registry. I have my script in GIT HUB repo.
In Build trigger selected repository hosting option as GitHub and Authenticated.

STEP: 1: Selected git hub source repository

[image]

STEP:2: Selected my git hub repo and authenticated.

[image]

STEP 3: Created trigger using docker file option.

[image]

STEP 4: Trigger ran & I got build failed.

[image]

Build log

```
starting build "5b04afe3-b669-48c6-83b1-58342f918256"

FETCHSOURCE
Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/
From https://source.developers.google.com/p/project-id/r/github-dhandapanisattanathan-gcb
* branch 59182f2dd5caffcc224d49299595056afd64d295 -> FETCH_HEAD
HEAD is now at 59182f2 ver 2
BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /workspace/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
ERROR
ERROR: build step "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:bb4f74d4d598896f932f4d2a5b12b3a816f5f6d3c9cf1f50d0bdd98fd4004d2d" failed: exit status 1
```

I got this issue unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Docker file path: lstat /workspace/Dockerfile: no such file or directory.

I don't know what I missed here. But each push in git hub trigger running automatically with build failed.

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The contents of `/workspace` are the contents of your git repository; in this case, https://github.com/dhandapanisattanathan/gcb. Your repository has no `Dockerfile`, so you can't use that non-existent `Dockerfile` to build.

It looks like your repository is for a GAE standard app. It's probably possible to transform it into a runnable container, but I don't know exactly what you would put in your Dockerfile to make it happen.

Comment: Thanks, John Asmuth, kindly guide me how to use Dockerfile in my GITHUB.

Comment: There are many tutorials out there for writing a `Dockerfile`. Once you have one, its presence in your repository will cause the build trigger you've already created to use it.

A simple one that doesn't use your could would be `FROM ubuntu`. That will push an image identical to `ubuntu` when you build.

Comment: Thanks, John Asmuth, I tried with a Dockerfile. I got success. But I need after build trigger How to push image to GAE SE. I updated my dockerfile and logs in this link. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qCwSn3ptB4re7Bo_Sl_Sp94fwhN6g45PqPLeBMuUDt8/edit#gid=0.Please help me What I missed?

Comment: GAE Standard does not run container images. For that, you need GAE Flexible, and you can deploy an image with `gcloud app deploy --image_url=gcr.io/yourproject/yourimage`.

Comment: Thanks, John Asmuth. I want to auto-deploy when build trigger gets success.Is this possible? or Can deploy to run this manually gcloud app deploy --image_url=gcr.io/yourproject/yourimage.Please help me

Comment: You can deploy from your build trigger by running `gcloud app deploy --image-url=myimage` inside the build.

```
<snip your existing build process resulting in gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/my-image>
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/my-image']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy', '--image-url=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/my-image', 'app.yaml']
```